# How does Arduino WiFi Shield connect to Blynk and How can I use ESP Module to connect to blynk?

Tags: esp8266, wifi

I was actually quite impressed how easily Blynk gets connected to Arduino. So I had a doubt how does Arduino WiFi Shield allow Arduino Uno to connect to blynk ? And my second doubt is how can I use the ESP boards to connect to blynk using Windows10 ( for steps ) ?
Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

> how does Arduino WiFi Shield allow Arduino Uno to connect to blynk

Blynk is just a web service. The WiFi shield connects your board to the internet and sends data to that web service. The Blynk app is just an interface to that web service.

> how can I use the ESP boards to connect to blynk using Windows10?

That makes no sense. You can connect an MCU to Blynk through something like an ESP8266 board (or program the ESP8266 board directly to communicate with Blynk). It is merely a network interface.

Windows 10 is not an MCU, and you already have an internet connection on it. If you want to communicate with Blynk from Windows 10 I suggest you look at the documents to see if there is an API you can use from your own programs, or a web interface you can view in your browser of choice.

Windows 10 and ESP8266 are two completely alien concepts.